# Which methods are always worth defining for Activities and Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I fully understand this is more of an opinion question, but when creating Activity and Fragment classes, which methods are worth defining?

For example I assume it is good practice to flesh out `onSaveInstanceState` for activities.

Comment: Any of the lifecycle methods but really it's dependent on what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all of the lifecycle methods, but it depends on what your app does. For example, you can use onCreate to initialize some stuff like Google Analythics, a database, and you can start loading data. I usually use onPause and onResume to stop and restart runnables which run continuously, to avoid getting any errors. And finally, in the onStop method you can do some data saving. 
It pretty much depends on your case.

Comment: Very far from "all of them". Do you know how many methods are actually in the base `Activity` class?